# Return when a value changes

Tags: dax

This is my data

```
SerialNumber  Reading  Date
A             4        10/30/2019
A             4        10/29/2019
A             3        10/28/2019
B             11       10/30/2019
B             9        10/29/2019
B             6        10/28/2019
C             25       10/30/2019
C             25       10/15/2019
C             25       10/13/2019
C             21       10/9/2019
C             21       10/3/2019
```

I need to be able to either create a measure or a calculated column that tells me the date of when each serial number last changed.  So i need this:

```
SerialNumber  Reading  Date          DateChanged
A             4        10/30/2019    10/28/2019
A             4        10/29/2019    10/28/2019
A             3        10/28/2019    10/28/2019
B             11       10/30/2019    10/29/2019
B             9        10/29/2019    10/29/2019
B             6        10/28/2019    10/29/2019
C             25       10/30/2019    10/9/2019
C             25       10/15/2019    10/9/2019
C             25       10/13/2019    10/9/2019
C             21       10/9/2019     10/9/2019
C             21       10/3/2019     10/9/2019
```

Here is the code I tried, but it only gave me the max date for each SerialNumber

```
Column = CALCULATE(
MAX(
SMU_Lookup[Date]),
FILTER(
ALL(SMU_Lookup),
 SMU_Lookup[Reading] < MAX(SMU_Lookup[Reading])
 && SMU_Lookup[SerialNumber] = EARLIER(SMU_Lookup[SerialNumber])
)
)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you mean the date when the reading for each serial number changes?

Comment: yes, sorry i didn't clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I first created a measure (a variable may have worked here too) to hold the max reading for each SerialNumber

```
MaxReading = CALCULATE(MAX(SMU_Lookup[Reading]),ALLEXCEPT(SMU_Lookup, SMU_Lookup[SerialNumber]))
```

Then I created the calculated column LastUpdate as follows

```
LastUpdate = CALCULATE(MAX(SMU_Lookup[Date]), FILTER(ALLEXCEPT(SMU_Lookup, SMU_Lookup[SerialNumber]), SMU_Lookup[Reading] < [Max Reading]))
```

Simple enough and it works for the instances where there are multiple readings with the same SerialNumber and Date.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the calculated column you are looking for:

```
DateChanged =
VAR max_date =
    MAXX (
        ALLEXCEPT ( 'SMU_Lookup', SMU_Lookup[SerialNumber] ),
        'SMU_Lookup'[Date]
    )
VAR reading_max_date =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'SMU_Lookup'[Reading] ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( 'SMU_Lookup', SMU_Lookup[SerialNumber] ),
        'SMU_Lookup'[Date] = max_date
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( SMU_Lookup[Date] ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( 'SMU_Lookup', SMU_Lookup[SerialNumber] ),
        'SMU_Lookup'[Reading] <> reading_max_date
    )
```

1. The ALLEXCEPT-function returns a table with the rows where the SerialNumber is the same as the SerialNumber in the current row.
2. The MAXX function returns the latest date for that table.
3. [VAR reading_max_date] holds the reading for the max_date for each SerialNumber.
4. After the RETURN statement the MAX(Date) is calculated where the Reading differs from reading_max_date.

Comment: This may work, however when I try to apply it to my dataset I get an error saying: There's not enough memory to complete this operation.
I am guessing because I have over a million rows this is struggling to work

Comment: try it on a subset

Comment: I tried it on a subset and it didn't quite work. It actually only seemed to work on serial numbers whose reading changed on the max date but at an earlier time. For example:
```table
SerialNumber Reading Date                           DateChanged
A                    10           10/31/2019 1:06:03   10/31/2019 1:01:46
A                    9             10/31/2019  1:01:46  10/31/2019 1:01:46
B                    15           10/31/2019  3:23:05  10/31/2019 3:23:05
B                    11           10/29/2019  1:17:02  10/31/2019 3:23:05
```

Comment: I edited my query to eliminate the time stamp but I still get the same result

Comment: My solution works with the dataset you provided in your original post. When there are multiple readings for the same day, this off course changes things. Please provide an accurate dataset with the expected results.

Comment: Yes, it's difficult to capture every single nuance in a dataset. My apologies. However, I was able to answer my own question, which I will post now. Thanks for the push in the right direction